# Dailymotion android SDK - Player control issue

Tags: android, webview, dailymotion-api

I integrated dailymotion web player in my android lollipop device. But right now i am facing following problem

steps followed :

1. Pressed play fullscreen icon in player controls
2. Then press exit fullscreen in player controls

I am getting black screen, but video is playing background. please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is a bug on this specific version of Android only, it will be fixed soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please download the last version of the SDK at https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-android, this issue has been fixed with this version.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I also like to ask you about the play and pause functionality. In some android version play and pause can be done clicking anywhere on the player.Is it done purposefully

Answer (score -1):

```
override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        playerWebView.onPause()
        playerWebView.pauseTimers()  
    }
override fun onResume() {
super.onResume()
playerWebView.onResume()
        playerWebView.resumeTimers()
    }

override fun onBackPressed() {
when {
isPlayerFullscreen -> onFullScreenToggleRequested()
playerWebView.canGoBack() -> playerWebView.goBack()
else -> release()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to provide useful answers.